# What is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}$, where $a_k$ is the $k$th "generalized" fibonacci number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

The following sequence is given:

\begin{align*}
a_1,a_2,..., a_n=1\\
a_{m}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{m-k},m>n
\end{align*}

What is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}$? Or how fast is the value of this expression growing with respect to $n$?

E.g. for $n=2$ it is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but is there a more general expression for any $n$?

Thank you

Comment: Is $f(x) = x^n - x^{n-1}- \cdots  -x -1$ irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$?  If so, and the zeros of $f(x)$ are $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$ then the limit will be one of the $r_i$, I think the one largest in magnitude.

Comment: Maybe this is true even if $f(x)$ is not irreducible, I need to think some more.

Comment: There is a lot of info on the wiki entry of [Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers) In particular, the limit of ratio $r$ is the root of $x + x^{-n} = 2$ closest to $2$ and the limit of this limit $r$ goes to $2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Malcolm It should be true in both cases and can be formalized by means of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $n$-fibonacci numbers satisfy the recurrence

$$a_{m+n}=a_{m+n-1}+a_{m+n-2}+\cdots+a_{m+1}+a_{m}.$$

The algorithm listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) shows that, for some constants $c_1,\cdots,c_n$,

$$a_m=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \alpha_i^m,$$

where $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^n-\left(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1\right)$. You seek to find the root of this polynomial with the largest magnitude.

This does not have a "nice" closed form as far as I am aware (although there might be some solution involving trigonometric functions; I'll edit this post if I come up with anything), but there is a way to determine the limit of this quantity as $n\to\infty$ (we call this $c$):

Multiplying this polynomial by $x-1$ gives the substantially easier to work with

$$x^{n+1}-2x^n+1.$$

It is clear that for all roots $z$ of this, $|z|^{n+1}\leq 1+2|z|^n$; however, for any real $r>2$, there exists an integer $n$ such that this is not satisfied. Thus, we obtain that $c\leq 2$. In addition, the polynomial evaluated at $2$ is positive while evaluated at $2-\epsilon$ it gives

$$1-\epsilon(2-\epsilon)^n,$$

which becomes negative for sufficiently large $n$; so for any real $r<2$ there exists a root between $r$ and $2$ if $n$ is large enough, so $c\geq 2$. We infer that $\boxed{c=2}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can recover the generalized golden ratio here by expanding the limit:

$$\phi=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{F_{k+1-r}}{F_k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{F_{k+1-r}}{F_{k+1-r+1}}\frac{F_{k+1-r+1}}{F_{k+1-r+2}}\cdots \frac{F_{k-1}}{F_k}=1+\phi^{-1}+\phi^{-2}+\cdots+\phi^{-(n-1)}=\frac{1-(1/\phi)^{n}}{1-1/\phi}$$

This isn't explicitely solvable, but you'll find more discussion on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Higher_orders

Comment: And solving your expression for $\phi$ gives $\phi^{n+1} - 2\phi^n +1 = 0$ which is the same expression as in Carl Schildkraut's answer.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The generalized golden ratio is a root of $$x^n-x^{n-1}-...-x-1=0$$Which could be changed to $$x^{n+1}-2x^n+1=0$$Like in @CarlSchildkraut's answer. This could be obtained using the partial sum formula for geometric series. Anyways, divide by $x^n$: $$x+\frac{1}{x^n}=2$$As $n$ gets larger and larger, the second fraction approaches zero, so the largest $x$ must approach $2$.

Note that $x=1$ is a viable solution to the above equation.